# Laravel 5.3 Controller __construct called before middleware

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have a Controller parent class which takes some attributes added to the `$request` by the middleware and makes them available to all child classes.

So in my middleware `handle()` function I have:

```
$request->attributes->add(['project' => $project]);
```

And in my Controller `__construct()` I have:

```
$this->project = $request->attributes->get('project');
```

This was working fine in 5.2, but since upgrading to 5.3, I've realised the Controller `__construct()` is called before my middleware `handle()` function, and so the 'project' attribute is `null`.

Does anyone know why the middleware is being called after the Controller?
Has something changed from 5.2 to 5.3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is something that's changed in 5.3:

https://laravel-news.com/2016/08/controller-construct-session-changes-in-laravel-5-3/

So now you can call middleware in the Controller constructor like this:

```
$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->project = $request->attributes->get('project');

    return $next($request);
});
```

Because the controller middleware will be called last, this way you can access the request attributes in the class after the route middleware has set them.

Cheers.